# Trying to override jinja ChoiceReloader in a Pelican Plugin

Tags: python, jinja2, pelican

I have a plugin where I am trying to load a my_assets python package before loading the templates from the folder.

The error I receive is: `CRITICAL: No assets environment configured in Jinja2 environment`

```
def foo(generator):
    self._templates = {}
    self._templates_path = []
    self._templates_path.append(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(self.theme, 'templates')))
    self._templates_path += self.settings['EXTRA_TEMPLATES_PATHS']

    theme_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    simple_loader = FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(theme_path, "themes", "simple", "templates"))

    self.env = Environment(
        trim_blocks=True,
        lstrip_blocks=True,
        loader=ChoiceLoader([
            PackageLoader('my_assets', 'templates'),
            FileSystemLoader(self._templates_path),
            simple_loader,
            PrefixLoader({'!simple': simple_loader})
            ]),
        extensions=self.settings['JINJA_EXTENSIONS'],
    )
    self.env.filters.update({'strftime': DateFormatter()})
    custom_filters = self.settings['JINJA_FILTERS']
    self.env.filters.update(custom_filters)
def register():
    signals.generator_init.connect(foo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this was in fact caused by my plugin conflicting with the pelican assets plugin that was using `self.env` as well. Only needed to override `self.env.loader`.

Just ended up using

```
self.env.loader = ChoiceLoader([
            PackageLoader('my_assets', 'templates'),
            FileSystemLoader(self._templates_path),
            simple_loader,
            PrefixLoader({'!simple': simple_loader})
            ])
```